# display the same data from one MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kcsX.png)

**script :**

```
SELECT 
tb_biodata.nama_lengkap as nama, 
tb_biodata.jenis_pegawai, 
tb_biodata.cabang,
tb_penilaian.tanggal,
case when tb_user.grup = 'satu' and tb_user.jabatan = 'kepegawaian' then rata_rata end AS penilai1, 
case when tb_user.grup = 'satu' and tb_user.jabatan = 'mg' then rata_rata end AS penilai2, 
case when tb_user.cabang = 'Majapahit 605' and tb_user.jabatan = 'amg' then rata_rata end AS penilai3

FROM tb_biodata 
inner join tb_penilaian ON tb_biodata.kode_biodata = tb_penilaian.kode_biodata
inner join tb_user ON tb_penilaian.kode_user = tb_user.kode_user 
where tb_biodata.jenis_pegawai = 'pegawai kependidikan'
```

***how to make the data into one line how***

Comment: Don't post images make it as a text and post it.

Comment: Add some more details, edit your post? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` and for the case use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Assuming `nama_lengkap` is unique and then query will be as below.

If there will be duplicate try using primary Key in `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
tb_biodata.nama_lengkap AS nama, 
tb_biodata.jenis_pegawai, 
tb_biodata.cabang,
tb_penilaian.tanggal,
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN tb_user.grup = 'satu' AND tb_user.jabatan = 'kepegawaian' THEN rata_rata END) AS penilai1, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN tb_user.grup = 'satu' AND tb_user.jabatan = 'mg' THEN rata_rata END) AS penilai2, 
GROUPCONCAT(CASE WHEN tb_user.cabang = 'Majapahit 605' AND tb_user.jabatan = 'amg' THEN rata_rata END) AS penilai3
FROM tb_biodata 
INNER JOIN tb_penilaian ON tb_biodata.kode_biodata = tb_penilaian.kode_biodata
INNER JOIN tb_user ON tb_penilaian.kode_user = tb_user.kode_user 
WHERE tb_biodata.jenis_pegawai = 'pegawai kependidikan'
GROUP BY nama;
```